# onSingleTapConfirmed invoked also for click on 3-dots action bar button, which cause lot of trouble

Tags: android, events, android-actionbar, conflict

In my app i show\hide sys-ui such as navigation\status bar.
i'm doing it by consuming the 'onSingleTapConfirmed' event and managed to toggle betwwen hide\show these ui-sys :

```
@Override
public boolean onSingleTapConfirmed(MotionEvent event) {

    switch (event.getAction()) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            if (sysBarsAreVisible) {
                hideSystemUI();
            } else {
                showSystemUI();
            }
            break;
    }

    return true;
}
```

This works just fine. navigation and status bars show and hide as i expected.
the problem is that when i try to press the 3dot button (...) in the action-bar the single-tap event is invoking and hiding the action-bar and the float menu that show-up and is gone right after.

any idea how can i solve it ?  how to recognize that the 3-dot button is pressed and skip the all show\hide operation.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I solved similar problem by calculating if touch coordinates are within view bounds or outside.

Answer (score 0):

According to **Adam Fręśko** answer..
i added the folowing lines to my code:

```
@Override
public boolean onSingleTapConfirmed(MotionEvent event) {
    Log.d(TAG, "raw Y: " + event.getRawY());
    Log.d(TAG, "bar height: " + actionBar.getHeight());
    switch (event.getAction()) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            if (event.getRawY() > actionBar.getHeight() * 1.2) {

                if (sysBarsAreVisible) {
                    hideSystemUI();
                } else {
                    showSystemUI();
                }
                return true;
            }
    }

    return false;
}
```

i compared the original raw Y coordinate against the action-bar's height to know if the user's action was outside the action-bar bounds.
I also multiple action-bar's height in 1.2 to extend the bounds for those who have big fingers :-).

Works perfect, Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The better approach is to consume the event at the ACTION_UP, cause the ACTION_DOWN can be consumed by the ActionBar making the ACTION_UP not being fired in your listener.

Comment: i tried it, and ACTION_DOWN work much smoother if you want toggling status+navigation bars. the interaction while ACTION_UP seems to be very hard to achieved compared ACTION_DOWN.

Comment: Well, thats because your view dont have any other events (probably) in this case you would see the SwapingBars animation but would not have the onClickActions. Hope you understand